# UITableViewCell.textLable.text does not appear on iOS11.2 simulator at xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode9.2, ios11.2

TableViewController and TableViewCell are working properly for both iOS 10.2 and iOS 11.2 , **which is developed with Objective C and compiled by xcode 8**. Now I'd been upgraded my xcode to xcode 9.2. Then cell.textLabel.text are not appear at iOS 11.2 simulator. But with iOS 10.2 simulator , it is working properly. When I debug, evth is fine and also have data. But it was not showed on simulator. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it won't happen. Give a check if there's any deprecated code lines. Sometimes, it might not show error or warning, but can cause unexpected result.

Comment: Yes. I'd already found sth stupid. Table view was covered by other view. [self.view sendSubviewToBack:bg] is no longer support and replaced it with  " self.tableView.backgroundView = bg; " .  Solved.